# Javascript arguments gestion

Tags: javascript, arguments, discord

I have a command created in JS for discord such as =
*announcement channelID "message to send"
which is defined as follows:

```
const channelID = args [0];
const messageaenvoyer = message.content.substring (`* ad $ {channelID}` .length + 1);
```

It's quite easy knowing that the channelID has a fixed length.

Now, I would like to add a title:

```
*announcement channelID title message to send
```

How to define each argument knowing that title and message to send have variable sizes and are subject to several words

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Function or Api that is used to create and send the message, should follow a protocol, receiver function just need to know what protocol is used to transfer data.These are some simple protocols.

1. you can use delimiter like this

   ```
   //`channelId#title#message`
   var delimiter = "#"
   var msg = channelId + delimiter  + title + delimiter + message
   ```
2. you can use fixed length

   ```
   var titleMaxLength =22;
   var messageMaxLength = 200;
   var data = channelId + title.padEnd(titleMaxLength ,' ')
      + message.padEnd(messageMaxLength ,' ')
   ```
3. the best way is using Json

   ```
   var msg = JSON.stringify({
      channelId: channelId,
      title:title,
      message:message })
   ```
4. you can also add metadata to your message

   ```
   var msg = channelId + title + message + '.' + message.length
   ```

Example for first one :

```
var delimiter = '#'

function sender(channelId, title, message) {
  var msg = channelId + delimiter + title + delimiter + message
  return msg
}

function receiver(msg) {
  var res = msg.split(delimiter)
  console.log(res)
}

var _msg = sender('123456', 'test', 'This is a test')
console.log(_msg)
receiver(_msg)
```